# Trouble left-aligning UIButton title (iOS/Swift)

Tags: swift, uibutton, title, text-alignment, leftalign

I'm having a problem left-aligning a `UIButton`'s text. I also tried changing it to `.Right` but it still stays centered. I also tried `aButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 0)` instead of `aButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Left` but that doesn't change anything either. Is there an alternative way to programmatically change the alignment of a `UIButton` title's?

```
        allButtonViews = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 44, 100, 100))
        allButtonViews.backgroundColor = .redColor()

        let campusButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 70)
        aButton.setTitle("A", forState: .Normal)
        aButton.titleLabel?.textColor = .blueColor()
        aButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Left
        aButton.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()

        sortView.addSubview(aButton)
        view.addSubview(allButtonViews)
```

[image]

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Try this:

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

Comment: Is there any setting in Xcode that would enable same functionality?

Comment: Add a user-defined runtime attribute with contentHorizontalAlignment as an NSNumber with value of 0-3 for center, left, right, and fill.

Comment: .Left has been renamed => .left.

Answer (score 21):

**Updated for Swift 3 or Swift 4**

```
yourButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```