# UIButton title alignment not changing to right direction in RTL

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton, xcode8

I am having an application in both LTR and RTL languages. Everything is fine but the UIButton title alignment is not changing to right though the UIButton flips itself.
Here is the screenshot:
[image: UIButton in RTL]

[image: Alignment Given]

Constraints given for default language english:

[image: Constraints given for default language english:]

What is the issue and why it happens? Do we need to set the title programatically aligned to right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use right alignment from storyboard as

[image]

or from programmatically as

```
buttonShowOnMap.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left//For left alignment

buttonShowOnMap.contentHorizontalAlignment = .right//For right alignment
```

Comment: what for left alligment . My application supports both RTL and LTR so setting in storyboard will no work

Comment: This answer supports both, rtl and ltr: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464708/trouble-left-aligning-uibutton-title-ios-swift/36464814

Comment: in newer XCode.InterfaceBuilder they have included a leading and trailing Alignment option, that can be useful

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer did not help me. But following snippet worked to support both RTL and LTR languages automatically:

```
// makes button content support RTL <-> LTR
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .leading

// makes titleLabel support RTL <-> LTR
button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .natural
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea why happening but you must subclass UIButton so that you can override `alignmentRectInsets`.

```
override func alignmentRectInsets() -> UIEdgeInsets {
    var insets: UIEdgeInsets
    if (Left_Side_Button) {
        insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 7.0, 0, 0)
    }
    else {
        // Right Button
        insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 7.0)
    }
    return insets
}
```

And achieve it by above code.

Comment: are you sure its a bug?

Comment: Don't know exactly but no ideas why happening.